# How to keep only unique values and remove ALL duplicate values based on some flag from an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I am working on typical case where I want to sort URLs from multidimensional array based on case insensitive basis and also their is status associated with URL. If user set multiple urls with different status then I want to get the only one url with the status set to false out of duplicate urls.

Original array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [url] => www.abc.com
        [status] => true
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [url] => www.123.com
        [status] => true
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [url] => www.abc.com
        [status] => true
    )


[3] => Array
    (
        [url] => www.Abc.com
        [status] => false
    )
)
```

Final result I want:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [url] => www.abc.com
        [status] => false
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [url] => www.123.com
        [status] => true
     )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filtered = array();

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $key = strtolower($url['url']);
    if (!isset($filtered[$key]) || $filtered[$key]['status']) {
        $filtered[$key] = $url;
    }
}

var_dump($filtered);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot! I am new to php and still in learning phase.
    I am getting the following array after executing:
    But it changes the array original structure.
    This is the existing output:
    `array(2) {
    ["www.abc.com"]=>
    array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(11) "www.Abc.com"
    ["status"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    }
    ["www.123.com"]=>
    array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(11) "www.123.com"
    ["status"]=>
    string(4) "true"
    }
    }`
    
    I want output as stated in original post. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Use `array_values()` if you want to get rid of the keys. The most important takeaway from my answer is the *algorithm* of simply using array keys for uniqueness. Modify as needed.

Comment: how can we modify above algorithm  if We want to use it with similar data but as in terms of array of object?

Comment: My actual data is as follows which `array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'url' => 'www.abc.com',
       'visibility' => false,
    )),
    1 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'url' => 'www.xyz.com',
       'visibility' => true,
    )),
    2 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'url' => 'www.Abc.com',
       'visibility' => false,
    ))
  ),`   How can I apply the same algorithm. When I apply above algorithm it gives NULL array. Please can a take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        'url' => 'www.abc.com',
        'status' => 'true'
    ),
    array(
        'url' => 'www.123.com',
        'status' => 'true'
    ),
    array(
        'url' => 'www.abc.com',
        'status' => 'true'
    ),
    array(
        'url' => 'www.Abc.com',
        'status' => 'false'
    )
);

function tolower($v) {
    return array('url'=>strtolower($v['url']),'status'=>$v['status']);
}
$arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize",array_map("tolower", $arr))));
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but wont give me the output array as expected.